# OpenCL: Type conversion overhead

Tags: optimization, opencl

What is the cost of casting a variable to a different type in OpenCL?

**Example:** I want to take dot product of 2 `int3` vectors (AFAIK `dot()` isn't overloaded for `int3`s), so instead of implementing `dot()` by myself in unvectorized way, I want to vectorize the code by using the native `dot()` for `float3`. First I convert the 2 vectors to `float3`s and then I cast the result to `int`.

Which of the two functions, `foo` and `bar`, is less time consuming (and why)?

```
inline int foo(int3 a, int3 b) {
  return a.x*b.x + a.y*b.y + a.z*b.z;
}

inline int bar(int3 a, int3 b) {
  return (int)dot(convert_float3(a), convert_float3(b));
}
```

Comment: @AndreasPapadopoulos I agree. By the way, do you know about some more granular way of profiling – i.e. seeing execution time for each individual command of kernel (something like Apple's Metal has), rather than just seeing execution time of the *whole* kernel?

Comment: @AndreasPapadopoulos to illustrate the idea better, take a look at [this profiling session image](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/3DDrawing/Conceptual/OpenGLES_ProgrammingGuide/Art/xcode_gpu_overview_program_2x.png) in XCode. It shows percentage of time spent on each line of code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As has been suggested in the comments, measuring is going to be the most useful tool in practice, and the cost of individual instructions is heavily dependent on hardware architecture, but also the compiler.

Nevertheless, a comparison to other operations is useful, and at least AMD publishes a list of the instruction throughput for their devices in [this section of their OpenCL optimisation guide](http://developer.amd.com/tools-and-sdks/opencl-zone/amd-accelerated-parallel-processing-app-sdk/opencl-optimization-guide/#50401334_43738), and this includes float-to-int and int-to-float conversion.

In your particular case, I strongly suspect your "vectorising" attempts will have detrimental effects. Most modern GPUs aren't SIMD processors in the CPU SIMD sense. The threads run in lock-step, but each thread operates on scalars. A "horizontal" operation like a dot product may not be particularly efficient even if the GPU does use per-thread SIMD.

If you can limit the range of each of your integers to 24 bits, a series of `mad24()` and `mul24()` calls will most likely be fastest. But again - measure. Try the different options on a range of hardware, and run them lots of times, applying basic stats to make sure you aren't just seeing random variation/overhead.

A separate thing to note with regard to integer-to-float conversions is that such conversions are often "free" when you sample as floats from an image object containing integers.